# Application scoped bean generating a really weird result

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, javabeans

I'm really confused and I ask for your help, after checking this lots of times.

I have a MySQL table with quotes I need to show at the homepage of this website I'm creating. They are exhibited with this code here

```
<h:outputText value="#{fraseMB.aleatoria.frase}"></h:outputText>
<h:outputText value=" (#{fraseMB.aleatoria.autor})"></h:outputText>
```

As you may see, the idea is to show the quote (frase, in Portuguese) and the author's name (autor, in Portuguese).

This code is backed by the following application scoped bean:

```
package net.isalicos.frase;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="fraseMB")
@ApplicationScoped
public class Frase implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1211720749246194248L;

    private int contador;

    private FraseVO aleatoria;
    private FraseDAO dao;
    private List<FraseVO> lista;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.contador = 0;
        dao = new FraseDAO();
        try {
            lista = dao.getList();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

        }
    }

    public FraseVO getAleatoria() {
        if(this.contador >= lista.size()) {
            contador = 0;
        }
        this.aleatoria = lista.get(contador);
        contador++;
        return this.aleatoria;
    }

    public void setAleatoria(FraseVO aleatoria) {
        this.aleatoria = aleatoria;
    }

}
```

As you may see, the idea is rotating the list. When it reaches the end, the counter (contador, in Portuguese) is reset to 0 and the quotes are shown from the beginning all over again. With lots of people accessing the site at the same time, things won't get too boring and predictable...

The list of quotes is retrieved by a DAO object with the following code:

```
private String queryBase() {
    String qry = "SELECT t1.id,t1.frase,t1.autor,t1.idioma";
    qry += " FROM frases AS t1";
    return qry;
}

public List<FraseVO> getList() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    List<FraseVO> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    FraseVO frase;
    String qry = queryBase();
    qry += " ORDER BY id";

    ResultSet rs = getResult(qry);
    while (rs.next()) {
        frase = new FraseVO();
        frase.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
        frase.setFrase(rs.getString("frase"));
        frase.setAutor(rs.getString("autor"));
        frase.setIdioma(rs.getString("idioma"));
        lista.add(frase);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Up to this point everything is fine, everything is orthodox and simple. Now we have the weird part!

When I go to the homepage it show a quote but with the wrong author. It shows the author in the next record of the table. For instance, if the quote is in record #1, the author is the one in record #2.

I tried everything. At first I assumed it was the scope of my bean. Initially it was RequestScoped and it was reasonable to assume it was advancing a record from one request to another. But then I changed it to `ViewScoped`, `SessionScoped` and finally to `ApplicationScoped`, obtaining the same results!

It is probably something very simple, but I confess I just can't see where is the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the counter starts at **0**. When you call `#{fraseMB.aleatoria.frase}`, the `getAleatoria()` method is invoked, getting result **0** from the list and incrementing the counter. The counter value is now **1**.

Then you call `#{fraseMB.aleatoria.autor}`. Again the `getAleatoria()` method is invoked. It now returns result **1** from the list. The counter is again incremented and its value is now **2**.

This is the reason your phrases and authors don't match.

Probably the easiest way to work around this, is to use [`c:set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/), and store the phrase in a temporary variable:

```
<c:set var="frase" value="#{fraseMB.aleatoria}" scope="request" /> 
<h:outputText value="#{frase.frase}"></h:outputText>
<h:outputText value=" (#{frase.autor})"></h:outputText>
```

Comment: I thought it would return a single quote when rendering the page. Maybe it sounds stupid, but that's what I thought! Thanks! I knew it was simple but I was already tired of looking at this code and nothing make sense anymore.